# Unity : Keyboard working for Desktop app but not for Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, input

I am trying to develop a game like Wordle in Unity which should have a Grid of blocks and each block should be able to take a letter as an input and show it on that block.

I am using this code to take input.

```
private static readonly KeyCode[] SUPPORTED_KEYS = new KeyCode[] {
        KeyCode.A, KeyCode.B, KeyCode.C, KeyCode.D, KeyCode.E, KeyCode.F,
        KeyCode.G, KeyCode.H, KeyCode.I, KeyCode.J, KeyCode.K, KeyCode.L,
        KeyCode.M, KeyCode.N, KeyCode.O, KeyCode.P, KeyCode.Q, KeyCode.R,
        KeyCode.S, KeyCode.T, KeyCode.U, KeyCode.V, KeyCode.W, KeyCode.X,
        KeyCode.Y, KeyCode.Z
    };

if(Input.GetKeyDown(SUPPORTED_KEYS[i]))
{
  ........
  ........
}
```

It's working fine on Desktop and taking input from the hardware keyboard.

[image]

But on Android, by default the keyboard don't show up.

I manually tried to add a keyboard using this code:

```
    private TouchScreenKeyboard keyboard;

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default);
    }
```

But it's opening up an Input Text field along with the keyboard. And even after taking input, it's not reflecting in my grid using the same `Input.GeyKeyDown()` API.

[image]

What are my requirements?

1. I want the input letter to be inserted in the blocks that I am using for my game.
2. I do not want the Input Text Field to be shown along with the keyboard on Android.

Please help me to resolve this. I am very new to Unity. But, I have gone through many links over the web. But couldn't get a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a clean and perfect way to do this.

Firstly the input can be hidden with

```
TouchScreenKeyboard.hideInput = true;
keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default);
```

The android keyboard doesn't seem to send input events in this mode. What you could do would be poll it every frame

(code untested but this should hopefully point you in the right direction)

```
// in some update loop
var text = keyboard.text;
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    continue;

SetInput(text);
keyboard.text = "";
```